# Who is the oldest being in the universe?

Tags: doctor-who, age

The Face of Boe was apparently the oldest being "in the Isop Galaxy." Who or what was the oldest being in the greater universe?

Comment: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Saldaamir - 14th Oldest

Comment: Is Ashildir too obvious of an answer?

Comment: @JasonBaker Who, Me?

Comment: The point in time is relevant for your question, do you mean who was the oldest in the universe at the time the scenario in your question took place, do you mean who survived the longest at the end of the universe or do you mean who was the oldest of all time.

Comment: @JesseBarnett The being that lived the longest total amount of time.

Comment: Weeping Angels?

Comment: On a technical point, how do you consider the age of the doctor regarding "Heaven Sent" episode ?

Comment: The Silence is what i think

Comment: @RogueJedi longest total amount of time relative to what? Themselves? Earth? Gallifrey?

Comment: @orangedog Relative to every other living being.

Comment: @RogueJedi such a measurement is impossible in a universe where time travel is possible (or where special relativity holds).

Comment: There is also [the Beast](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Beast_%28The_Impossible_Planet%29).

Comment: @OrangeDog How long they have lived in total, compared to how long everyone else has lived in total.

Comment: The only way to answer this question is to decide who you want to be the answer, then clarify the question so that it works out to be them.

Comment: @RogueJedi you're missing the point of relativity. How are you supposed to measure how long someone has lived? Whose clock are you using?

Comment: @MrLister and many more (The Great Intelligence, Fenric, the Eternals etc.) depending on what sources you go by.

Comment: @OrangeDog The total number of [units of time, converted to earth time units of neccesary] their body has lived through, taking time travel into account.

Comment: What about brings without a body, or with multiple bodies? The Doctor could be 80, 2000, or billions of years old.

Comment: @OrangeDog I think you're being needlessly pedantic. If you have evidence the Doctor is the oldest being in the universe, put him. If the being has no body, substitute "soul" or "consciousness" or whatever applies.

Comment: The doctor was just an easy example of someone complicated. The correct answer is probably the Eternals, who have always existed, and thus are older than anything that hasn’t.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possibly [Ashildr (Me)](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Ashildr).

> Me was present at the very end of time, the last living being in the universe. To survive she created a bubble of reality among the ruins of the Cloisters on Gallifrey, passing the time watching the stars die while awaiting the Doctor and Clara's arrival. Five minutes before the final end of time, their stolen TARDIS appeared and Me knocked on the door.

So the end of time is [a LONG time away](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Universe#After)

> The end of the universe, also known as Event Two (PROSE: The Infinity Doctors), was variously projected to have occurred in 60 billion AD (AUDIO: Zagreus), 100 trillion AD (TV: Utopia) or, in another universe, 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 AD. (PROSE: The Infinity Doctors)

Since it's implied that she simply lived throughout time, that would make her potentially 100 trillion years old. She also states she's the last immortal alive.

Comment: However, she only started in 9th Century AD, and never overlapped her own timestream.

Comment: @OrangeDog True, but we can't point to anyone else even remotely that old. Even the Doctor is only 2000 years old.

Comment: The Doctor is peanuts. Rassilon was born long before him. Various beings existed before the Universe began.

Comment: Yes, but when did they *die*? Me is the only person left at the very end. If you have a better instance I'm all ears.

Comment: Death date minus birth date does not equal lifespan for any time/dimension/universe traveler. We just don't know how old Rassilon is. Even ignoring all the wibbly-wobbly that probably happened in the Last Great Time War, in the Big Finish audio adventures he spent significant "time" in a dimension where time doesn't exist. How do you count that? The question, as currently worded, is unanswerable. If the Face of Boe is Jack Harkness we have no idea how old they were when they died. It could be many times the duration of the Universe's existence.

Comment: At the point when the last Eternal left the Universe, how old were they? Infinitely old?

Comment: You also have other immortals like the Guardians and the Toymaker (who IIRC existed in a different universe before the creation of the current one) who, assuming they can't die as they say, could be older.

Answer (score -1):

The Face of Boe. There are many people considered to be the Face of Boe. Some of which are: Captain Jack or the Doctor.[image]

Comment: Do you have evidence to believe it's the Face of Boe and not the characters linked in the accepted anwer?

Comment: It would be odd to call the Face of Boe "the oldest being in the Isop Galaxy" if he was, in fact, the oldest being in the universe.